# How to use jquery UI modal on tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a page with multiple tabs. The tabs are created dynamically 
Each tab has it own content(page) load by ajax call. This work perfectely
Now, some pages have child pages. So i want to open the child page as modal(i am using jquery modal).When open modal1 on page 1, i shoulb be able to go to tab2 and look at page 2 without closing modal1(at content1 or page 1)
Problem: my modal cover the entire page and tabs. 
How do i make sure to use it modal on it own page.?

Comment: Set the option modal as false so you can interact with the rest of the page. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal

Comment: But i wanted to Block the page where the child belong to
I have the content Div ID of that page : parent_id

Comment: Do you have a working sample? It's a bit harder to see what you're trying to do. Does the modal needs to be inside the tab then? Couldn't it be placed outside of the tab?

Comment: Please show your markup.

Comment: please share the boilerplate code, don't expect others to do all the work from scratch just to reproduce your issue...

Comment: Sorry, I have an example in the following 
http://jsfiddle.net/CnEUh/2046/#&togetherjs=HbFHDA6qvx  
As you can see, I have TAb1 and Tab2. I want to be able to open dialog on tab1 , and still be able to navigate tab2, while a modal cover content 1 only

Comment: @davidkonrad

Here is the [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/voxcode/CnEUh/2047/)